# Why is the C++ thread/future overhead so big

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a worker routine (code below), which is running slower when I run it in a separate thread. As far as I can tell, the worker code and data is completely independent of other threads. All the worker does is to append nodes to a tree. The goal is having multiple workers growing trees in parallel.

**Can someone help me understand why there is (significant) overhead when running the worker in a separate thread?**

**Edit**:
Initially I was testing WorkerFuture twice, I corrected that and I now get the same (better) performance in the no thread and defer async cases, and considerable overhead when an extra thread is involved.

The command to compile (linux): g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -O3 -pthread

Here is the output (time in milliseconds):

```
Thread     : 4000001 size in 1861 ms
Async      : 4000001 size in 1836 ms
Defer async: 4000001 size in 1423 ms
No thread  : 4000001 size in 1455 ms
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

struct Data
{
    int data;
};

struct Tree
{
    Data data;
    long long total;
    std::vector<Tree *> children;

    long long Size()
    {
        long long size = 1;
        for (auto c : children)
            size += c->Size();
        return size;
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        for (auto c : children)
            delete c;
    }
};

int
GetRandom(long long size)
{
    static long long counter = 0;
    return counter++ % size;
}

void
Worker_(Tree *root)
{
    std::vector<Tree *> nodes = {root};
    Tree *it = root;
    while (!it->children.empty())
    {
        it = it->children[GetRandom(it->children.size())];
        nodes.push_back(it);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        nodes.back()->children.push_back(new Tree{{10}, 1, {}});
    for (auto t : nodes)
        ++t->total;
}

long long
Worker(long long iterations)
{
    Tree root = {};
    for (long long i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
        Worker_(&root);
    return root.Size();
}

void ThreadFn(long long iterations, long long &result)
{
    result = Worker(iterations);
}

long long
WorkerThread(long long iterations)
{
    long long result = 0;
    std::thread t(ThreadFn, iterations, std::ref(result));
    t.join();
    return result;
}

long long
WorkerFuture(long long iterations)
{
    std::future<long long> f = std::async(std::launch::async, [iterations] {
        return Worker(iterations);
    });

    return f.get();
}

long long
WorkerFutureSameThread(long long iterations)
{
    std::future<long long> f = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [iterations] {
        return Worker(iterations);
    });

    return f.get();
}

int main()
{
    long long iterations = 40000;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto total = WorkerThread(iterations);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Thread     : " << total << " size in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms\n";

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total = WorkerFuture(iterations);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Async      : " << total << " size in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms\n";

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total = WorkerFutureSameThread(iterations);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Defer async: " << total << " size in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms\n";

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total = Worker(iterations);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "No thread  : " << total << " size in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: @SidS, No, I create a single thread in the 3 slower cases, and no thread in the last case.

Comment: I don't see more than a single thread being created; however, I think you've alluded to the answer: no other work is happening, so having it done with no thread is going to be quicker than creating a thread to do it.

Comment: @Tas, I understand that, the goal is to have a few threads like this in parallel and I expect the performance to grow almost linearly up until the number of cores. I don't understand why I pay 0.3 seconds to do the work in a thread.

Comment: Your "Defer async" looks the same as your "Asyc".

Comment: Optimized build or not?

Comment: @Jesper, optimized with -O3, I added to the answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, they differ by the policy, one is supposed to start a new thread, the other isn't.

Comment: I think he's pointing out that in `main` you have `WorkerFuture()` twice and are missing `WorkerFutureSameThread()`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, Oh, my bad. I corrected and I now get the same speed in the no thread cases, and overhead in the others.

Comment: curiously, the time difference seems to be dependent on `iterations`, [here with `5000`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d7c134b6511a6a1) iterations, the overhead seems to be `~30ms` and increases as the iteration count goes up ([here at `10000`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cb00233c91588ab)). why this is though, I have no idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by dynamic memory management. When multiple threads are involved (even if the main thread does nothing), C++ runtime must synchronize access to dynamic memory (heap), which generates some overhead. I did some experiments with GCC and the solution of your problem is to use some scalable memory allocator library. For instance, when I used `tbbmalloc`, e.g.,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TBB_ROOT/lib/intel64/gcc4.7:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2
```

the whole problem disappeared.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in my code the destructor is called when the Worker exits, and the node deletion is taken into account in all cases. I removed the destructor, and the times went down a bit, but the difference is still there and it still is ~300 ms.

Comment: @kaspersky I completely rewritten my answer based on some more experiments I have done.

Comment: is g++'s default allocator so bad that it causes a 20%-30% increase in execution on separate threads? that doesn't seem like it should be right, but I can't think of anything else that could explain it.

Comment: Oh wow, that's nice, many thanks. I confirmed this by writing a custom allocator (not synchronized), and the difference went away :)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x This depends on glibc version, newer are better, but still worse than special scalable versions of `malloc`, such as those from TBB, tcmalloc, ...

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Few years ago, switching to TBB scalable `malloc` caused our HPC application to run _several times_ faster. Tcmalloc is even faster though with higher memory overhead. We are now experimenting with memory pools and small buffer optimizations (such as `small_vector`s from Boost) and again we are observing significant speedups. Dynamic memory issues are frequently main bottlenecks in multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. You do not do anything in parallel manner.
When extra thread is doing something main thread does nothing (waits for thread job to complete).

In case of thread you have extra thing to do (handle thread and synchronization) so you have a trade off.

To see any gain you have to do at least two things at the same time.

Comment: I understand there is a trade off, I just can't believe it can be 300 ms. And the difference increases with the number of nodes.